# How to pause the AWS ADOT Collector in Deployment Mode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, amazon-adot

I have successfully deployed the ADOT collector in deployment and as per Docs I can pause it so that I don't incur charges:

https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/adot-eks-add-on/installation#deployment-mode

> If you want to get more control of the Collector and create a standalone application, Deployment would be your choice. With Deployment, you can relatively easily scale up the Collector to monitor more targets, roll back to an early version if anything unexpected happens, pause the Collector, etc. In general, you can manage your Collector instance just as an application.

I can simply delete deployment but I want to know how to pause it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADOT PM here. Interesting question! Some context: you can think of our EKS add-on effectively as the upstream [OpenTelemetry operator](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator) behind an EKS API. Having said that:

> How can I pause [the ADOT collector] so that I don't incur charges.

Using the advanced config, you can set `collector.replicas` to `0`. See also our [docs](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/adot-eks-add-on/add-on-configuration) for further details. This will cause the custom controller, part of the OpenTelemetry operator, to scale the ADOT collector pods running to zero and with that you can reduce compute resource usage. Note that this will not effect the custom controller, however, meaning that you would still incur CPU & MEM usage for that component.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and yes even I thought the same either setting replicas to 0 or deleting the deployment. 

On a side note it is safe to a assume that the mentioned documentation is not accurate when it comes to `pause the collector`?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and which part of the docs are you referring to?

Comment: If you follow this link https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/adot-eks-add-on/installation#deployment-mode `With Deployment, you can relatively easily scale up the Collector to monitor more targets, roll back to an early version if anything unexpected happens, pause the Collector, etc. In general, you can manage your Collector instance just as an application.`